# Sorting of an index in Datetime format so that the first data of the day is the time 1:00

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I do not understand why this solution does not work to move forward one day in some rows of the series, working on the index.

```
curva_generacion.loc[curva_generacion.index.hour == 0].index = curva_generacion.loc[curva_generacion.index.hour == 0].index - pd.DateOffset(days=1)
```

This is my DataFrame, and with the previous solution I am unable to change the data:

```
                     **SVH.2.1 BIS**
**FECHA**                           
2015-01-01 00:00:00         0.00
2015-01-01 01:00:00         0.00
2015-01-01 02:00:00         0.00
[...]
2015-01-01 21:00:00         0.00
2015-01-01 22:00:00         0.00
2015-01-01 23:00:00         0.00
2015-01-02 00:00:00         0.00
2015-01-02 01:00:00         0.00
2015-01-02 02:00:00         0.00
```

When it is 0:00, the table includes the data in the following day. To be compatible with the table I already work with, the 0:00 data must belong to the previous day.

I have managed to filter well the data I need to change and subtract a day from it, but the index is not modified.

EDIT

I think I have a conceptual error that I have seen after testing the following code.

```
auxiliar1 = curva_generacion.loc[curva_generacion.index.hour == 0]
auxiliar1.index = auxiliar1.index - pd.DateOffset(days=1)
auxiliar1.index = auxiliar1.index.map(lambda t: t.replace(year=2015))
auxiliar2 = curva_generacion.loc[curva_generacion.index.hour != 0]
curva_generacion = pd.concat([auxiliar1, auxiliar2])
curva_generacion.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

With this code I extract the data from which I want to subtract a day, I do the operation, and I concatenate them and one with the data that I have not modified. When I re-sort the index, Python puts back as the first data of the day the one corresponding to 0:00.

What I really need is to sort an index where the first data of the day is the 1:00 a.m. data, and the last is the 0:00 data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest an option with resetting the index, setting the required values and then installing the index.

```
import pandas as pd

curva_generacion = curva_generacion.reset_index()

ind = curva_generacion['**FECHA**'].dt.hour == 0

curva_generacion.loc[ind, '**FECHA**'] = (curva_generacion.loc[ind, '**FECHA**'] -
                                          pd.DateOffset(days=1))
curva_generacion = curva_generacion.set_index('**FECHA**')

print(curva_generacion)
```

Output:

```
                     **SVH.2.1 BIS**
**FECHA**                           
2014-12-31 00:00:00                1
2015-01-01 01:00:00                2
2015-01-01 02:00:00                3
2015-01-01 21:00:00                4
2015-01-01 22:00:00                5
2015-01-01 23:00:00                6
2015-01-01 00:00:00                7
2015-01-02 01:00:00                8
2015-01-02 02:00:00                9
```

**Update:**
Updating indexes without resetting.
And an error when setting individual values: `'TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations'`. Rather, it concerns the installation of individual values, since if you reinstall everything, this will complete successfully.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
    
ind = curva_generacion.index.hour == 0
val_index = curva_generacion.index.values.copy()
val_index[ind] = val_index[ind] - np.timedelta64(1,'D')

curva_generacion.index = val_index
```

Comment: Thanks! What I do not understand is why my first solution is not working, Your solution is very simila, but you work on the columns, and I work directly on the index.

Comment: @nico probably the [indexes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.html)  are an immutable array. I also read in one book that indexes are immutable. I tried to install it for one index and the error says that the index cannot be changed:
curva_generacion.index[0] = curva_generacion.index[0] - pd.DateOffset(days=1) It is not clear why an error not occur when we try to change several indexes, which is misleading.

Comment: @nico found a way to change indexes without resetting.